# How to route multiple levels of nested resources in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, nested-attributes

I know I can specify nested resources on `routes.rb` in Rails 3 this way:

```
  resources :users do
    resources :posts 
  end
```

However, I would like to add `comments` to `posts`. What should I write in my `routes.rb` file? Is this the correct way? Can I keep nesting them?

```
  resources :users do
    resources :posts do
     resources :comments
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can keep nesting the way you have shown and things will work fine. There are quite a few sources that will tell you not to go crazy nesting routes though. Take a look at [Rails Best Practices](http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/11-needless-deep-nesting) for example (I think the article was created for rails 2 but the principals still apply). [Jamis Buck](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2007/2/5/nesting-resources) also blogged about this a while ago.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can keep nesting and nesting and nesting and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. What you wrote is the correct way.

Answer (score 1):

I've been interested in this same problem and I think you're suppose to do:

```
resources :users do
  resources :posts
end

resources :posts do
  resources :comments
end
```

Check out the [API on Resources](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Resources.html#method-i-resource).

Comment: Yeah, but if you do that you also end up with different routes than you originally posted.